# Base64 decode causes out of memory

Tags: jquery

I'm using MP3RecorderJS. It workkd well except that when the audio I'm recording gets past about 30 seconds, it fails as Javascript throws an out of memory error, which is due to the base64 data being too big.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
  recorderObject.exportMP3(function(base64_mp3_data) {
    var url = 'data:audio/mp3;base64,' + base64_mp3_data;
  });
```

This is where it fails as the Ajax function that follows isn't being read.

As mentioned, it works when I record audio for 15-30 seconds. Longer than that and it fails.

Any help is very much appreciated.

B

Comment: you  could lower the sampling rate maybe!

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Google it ,you must be using 44100Hz , slide it down to 22050Hz.

Comment: lowered the sampling rate but it still produces the error

Comment: hmm , you didn't get any increase in time limit ? if not use wav instead of mp3!

Comment: if this ain't working , you can use an external library like this: https://plugins.jquery.com/jquery-record/

Comment: @UbdusSamad yeah. wav gets rid of the error. error now comes when inserting sending the wav data via ajax then decoding

Comment: @UbdusSamad please don't be rude, just answer his question & wait for responses

Comment: Okay, Sorry, i Apologise! The OP replies after a very long time!